# How to use both Count() and Min/Max in sql

Tags: django, orm

I have the following table: `MyTable`

```
   name   | price
|-------------------|
|   a     |    10   |
|-------------------|
|   b     |     5   |
|-------------------|
|   a     |     7   |
|-------------------|
|   a     |     3   |
|-------------------|
|   a     |     12  |
|-------------------|
|   b     |     6   |
|-------------------|
|   c     |     2   |
|-------------------|
|   c     |     5   |
|-------------------|
```

I want to count the frequency of the `name` and need to get the `max_price` and `min_price` for each `name`.

The expected output is:

```
   name   | count   | min_price | max_price
|-------------------|----------------------|
|   a     |     4   |  3        |   12     | 
|-------------------|----------------------|
|   b     |     2   |  5        |   6      |
|-------------------|----------------------|
|   c     |     2   |  2        |   5      |
|-------------------|----------------------|
```

I would like to write Django ORM query. Please help me to achieve it.

Comment: Try this: `MyTable.objects.annotate(min_price=Min('price')).annotate(max_price=Max('price')).annotate(count=Count('name')).order_by()`

Comment: Hi @Ahtisham, this query is not returning the correct min_price and max_price.

Comment: You need no one when you have Dr Cooper (Willem Van Onsem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate the items with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Max, Min

MyModel.objects.values('name').annotate(
    count=Count('pk'),
    min_price=Min('price'),
    max_price=Max('price')
).order_by('name')
```